# Airflow HdfsSensor hdfs_conn_id

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to use the Hdfs_Sensor Operator from the edge node but run up against what the hdfs_conn_id should be

This is my dag:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.sensors import HdfsSensor as HdfsSensorImp
default_args = {
    'owner': 'anair',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2019,5,10),
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'HdfsSensor_test', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *')


hdfs_sense_open = HdfsSensorImp(
        task_id='hdfs_sense_open',
        filepath='/dev/dcdr/dv/coal/_SUCCESS',
        hdfs_conn_id='???',
        dag=dag)
```

What should be my hdfs_conn_id? New to airflow, any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you happen figure out what `hdfs_conn_id` looks like?

Comment: nope, I gave up on Airflow but you could try the following answers and select the one that worked out for you, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`hdfs_conn_id` refers to the name/id of your hdfs connection created on airflow.

You can create a new connection in the Airflow UI. 
Admin > Connections > Create Tab

Comment: So I created the connection, but it doesn't seem to run. How can I verify if the connection that I made is correct or not? It seems to make calls but it doesn't move on to the next task, when I checked out the logs, it makes multiple attempt to poke at the directory, pretty sure I am missing on something, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me!**

HDFS connection is pretty much like any sftp/ftp connection, so there will be not big of a deal if you create new alike that.

but, if you want to have a neat environment , you have to install its provider first with

```
pip3 install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs
```

(i was using python 3 so if you are using 2 just remove the 3 from above command)

after the installation was successful , restart the webserver & scheduler services, head to the Airflow UI > Admin > Connections > +

and there you can see in the Type that HDFS now exists.
just add enter the SSH stuff about the hdfs (Host, User , Pass, ..) and it will work.
Connection ID is what you later will use in your code.

Good luck.